# What do the "..." mean in virtual void foo(...) = 0;?

Tags: c++

Pretty simple question I think but I'm having trouble finding any discussion on it at all anywhere on the web.  I've seen the triple-dot's as function parameters multiple times throughout the years and I've always just thought it meant "and whatever you would stick here."  Until last night, when I decided to try to compile a function with them.  To my surprise, it compiled without warnings or errors on MSVC2010.  Or at least, it appeared to.  I'm not really sure, so I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 7):

They are va_args, or variable number of arguments. See for example [The C book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)

Comment: True. Note that they are an old hack from the times of C and are not really recommended in C++ because of the lack of type safety. I mean, they have their uses, but usually you can find a better alternative with C++ facilities. (btw, Mic? the Mic from gamedev.pl?)

Comment: except for those lazy folks who want to `catch` all exceptions! ;)

Comment: Absolutely, personally I try to always avoid them. And no, I'm not mic from gamedev.pl :)

Answer (score 4):

Triple dots means the function is [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (i.e. accepts a variable number of parameters). However to be used there should be at least a parameter... so having just "..." isn't an usable portable declaration.

Sometimes variadic function declarations are used in C++ template trickery just because of the resolution precedence of overloads (i.e. those functions are declared just to make a certain template instantiation to fail or succeed, the variadic function themselves are not implemented). This technique is named [Substitution failure is not an error (SFINAE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE).

Comment: Various applications of [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) are where the latter is used.

Comment: Added the link in the answer thanks. I'm not a big fan of this kind of hand-walking techniques, but for sure they're popular.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [ellipses](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/714-ellipses-and-why-to-avoid-them/) - basically saying that function accepts any number of arguments of any non-class type.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the  types of arguments, and the number of them are unspecified.  A concrete example with which you are probably familiar would be something like `printf(char *, ...)`

If you use printf, you can put whatever you like after the format string, and it is not enforced by the compiler.

e.g. `printf("%s:%s",8)`, gets through the compiler just the same as if the "expected" arguments are provided `printf("%s:%s", "stringA", "stringB")`.

Unless really necessary, it should be avoided, as it creates the potential for a run time error to occur, where it might otherwise have been picked up at compile time.  If there is a finite, enumerable variation in the arguments your function can accept, then it is better to enumerate them by overloading.